# How to get get raw packets send and recieved from TcpClient class?

Tags: c#, tcpclient

Does the TcpClient class keep track of the number of bytes sent, received, and  error counts or is there some other class that do something similar to that? I don't think the tcpclient class can do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No TcpClient does not keep such statistics. You could look at the interface statistics for pure send/receive (though it would include traffic other than TCP): [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.net.networkinformation.ipv4interfacestatistics)

Most of the time TcpClient is wrapped in another class (at least it is when I use it). It would be trivial to track send/receive counts with such a wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

TcpClient does not do that. You can write yourself a small class that tracks this state. You could derive from `Stream` and build a reusable stream that tracks all kinds of metrics, and otherwise just relays all commands to another stream.